# Storing a large number of geolocation records in cached ArrayList or always query them from MongoDB?

Tags: java, mongodb, caching, arraylist, geolocation

I'm working on a geolocation app. This app holds about 500K records in a MongoDB properly indexed. Each row has its own latitude and longitude recorded values. Thus, a client must recover 200 nearest points from those 500k rows. I have a concern with performance. At first I thought of keep all records(lat/lng info) in a cache manager or in-memory database. After that, a given point(lat/lng) could be compared to those values in cache. At this moment my doubts take place.

Would be good to store all those records in an ArrayList in a cache-manager and then compare geolocations of records to the geolocations in ArrayList in order to calculate the distances ?

With that approach I prevent a huge number of queries in MongoDB, in other hand, that could be wrong by keeping about 500K records(geolocation) in an ArrayList and then fetch ths list to retrieve the 200 nearest. If not wrong, at least it's a performance penalty I think.

How can I deal with that issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How big is each record? Holding a sorted map of a few hundred megabytes would/should be trivial.

Comment: Each record has 2 Strings and 1 UUID (longitude, latitude, UUID).

Comment: Yes it is perfectly viable to store a very large list in memory as long as you are aware that you are doing it. Calculate the expected size to see just how large it is. Keep in mind most of the time the JVM does not start with very much memory available. You will need to specify it to be larger with Xms and Xmx command line parameters. You might want to check available memory with `Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory()` before adding everything to the list to be sure. Make sure the user is aware there is a memory requirement.

Comment: ArrayList's aren't optimized for searching. Try a HashMap for exact searches or a TreeMap for range searches.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Keeping your data in-memory could be a performance enhancement. But when you have 500k records in an ArrayList and want to search for the 200 nearest to a given point, this means that every single one of the 500k records will have to be checked for every single request. This will take a while. Likely much, much longer than MongoDB would take.

But you can improve performance by doing the same thing MongoDB is doing with their geo-indexes: Use a smarter data-structure optimized for searching. An [R-Tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rtree), for example. In a well-balanced R-Tree, searching for all records in a given area is an operation with a runtime complexity of `log n` instead of `n` for an array-list. For 500k entries, that would be an improvement of several orders of magnitude.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm considering to store all 500k records in a R-Tree structure and then perform searching. 500k records should required about 20 Gb of memory. Am I right? Each record is an object with three attributes(2 Strings and 1 UUID).

Comment: @blackjack depends on the size of the strings. A string requires one byte per ASCII character (more for unicode characters) plus some bytes for meta-information. But note that Java does automatic string-pooling, so when you have duplicates, they won't take double memory. When we assume 1kByte per object, that would be 500MB of memory.